# Returning array without given object

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutability, deep-copy

I have the following interfaces in my Angular app:

```
interface Reservation {
  id: string;
  from: Date;
  to: Date;
}

interface Bedroom {
  id: string;
  reservations: Array < Reservation > ;
}

interface House {
  id: string;
  bedrooms: Array < Bedroom >;
}
```

At some point, I have to delete a `Reservation` from within a certain `Bedroom` from within the `Array` of `House`s and return a copy of the whole `House` `Array` only without that deleted `Reservation` item.

I cannot mutate the existing `Array` of `House`s. How should I do this?

Comment: The question seems to be self-explanatory. Make a deep copy, iterate over it and remove properties. Do you have problems with this approach? What did you try?

Comment: So I actually want to avoid iterating over each item for performance reason. I was wondering I can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(houses))` and then actually go "pluck?" the reservation object out of the resulting object then return it.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify...` can hardly be good for performance. You won't see it in deep copy implementations. You can either deep copy it and remove properties from it, or you can omit a property when copying an array by hand and check if you can do deep copy better than existing solutions like _,cloneDeep. You cannot avoid iteration because array processing cannot be done without iteration,

Answer (score 0):

You should use `splice` method on your array, combinet with clone of object (ie provided by underscore.js):
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp
http://underscorejs.org/#clone

It would be **something** (I did not check that code) like this:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
removeReservation(bedroom: Bedroom, reservation: Reservation): Bedroom {
    let position = bedroom.reservations.findIndex(checkingRes => {
         return checkingRes.id == reservation.id
    });
    let bedroomCopy = _.clone(bedroom);
    bedroomCopy.reservations.splice(position, position + 1);
    return bedroomCopy;
}
```

If you want to pernamently delete reservation, you just ommit the clone operation.

```
removeReservation(bedroom: Bedroom, reservation: Reservation): Bedroom {
    let position = bedroom.reservations.findIndex(checkingRes => {
         return checkingRes.id == reservation.id
    });
    bedroom.reservations.splice(position, position + 1);
    return bedroom;
}
```

Comment: splice is destructive, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by desructive? It is just REMOVING object from array. That's the case of question, I guess ;)

Comment: The question says 'I cannot mutate the existing Array of Houses.'

Comment: Ok.. Give me a sec :)

Comment: Now better ? :)